# Let $f:[a,b]\times[c,d]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Prove continuity of the function $F$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b]\times[c,d]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Prove continuity of the function $F:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$F(s)=\int_c^d f(s,t)dt$

*Here's what I tried to do (with questions):

Since $f$ is continuous, $f$ is Riemann integrable. **(Can I conclude $f$ is separately continuous? that is $f(s,t)$ is continuous in $s$ for each fixed $t$.)**

Since $f$ is integrable, so linearity holds **(If not integrable, then linearity cannot hold, right?)** Thus, $|\int_c^df(x,t)dt-\int_c^df(y,t)dt|=|\int_c^d(f(x,t)-f(y,t))dt|$. **($t$ is the variable, and $x,y$ are fixed. So if $f(s,t)$ is continuous in $t$ for each fixed $s$, can we also conclude the same equality?)**

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, because the domain is compact, $\exists\delta>0$, such that $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x,t)-f(y,t)|<\frac{\epsilon}{|c-d|}$ **(Would $f$ be separately continuous be enough for this inequality?)**

If the above is correct, then the result follows, i.e.$F$ is continuous.

Comment: Your approach is correct. Just trying to answer a few of your questions: Yes, $f$ is separately continous since it is continous. If $f$ would not be integrable the question of linearity wouldnt really make sense since the integral wouldn't make sense. But it is integrable since it is continous.  I am not sure about your question about the equality, of course this equality holds for integrable functions. And no, $f$ being separately continous would not be enough. How would you obtain your $\delta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is fine.

To prove the continuity of $F$, separately continuous would be enough if $f$ is bounded by an integrable function.

Comment: Can you please explain? Thank you!

Comment: See this https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuity_under_Integral_Sign